# Customize JSON output of Forms/FormErrors

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I would like to customize the JSON output of all the SymfonyForms in my Application. Since this is the first time I am building such an Application I am unsure about the best place to put the code to. Right now I see two options:

1. A custom Handler within the `FOSRestBundle` as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html#custom-handler)
2. A Handler within the `JMSSerializerBundle` as mentioned [here](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers)

I guess that both ways will do the Job, but which one should I prefer here in terms of flexibility and maintainability. As already said above, I would like to change the output for ALL forms and the validation errors in my application. It would be very nice if a little example would be provided.

Right now I get this output if a validation Error occurs:

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": {
    "children": {
      "username": {},
      "password": {
        "children": {
          "first": {},
          "second": {}
        }
      },
      "email": {
        "errors": ["This value is already used."]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And would like to have something like that:

```
{
  "code": …,
  "message": …,
  "errors": {
    "<formname>": {
      …
      "email": "This value is already used." //errors concatenated to a string
      …
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in ahead!